# How to get all relationship types in neo4j DB using blueprints?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm using the blueprints API with a neo4j DB. Is there a way in blueprints to retrieve all the relationship types that exist among the nodes in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

The current API(1.2) of blueprints does not have any exposed method for providing all the labels on edges, but Neo4j [does](http://api.neo4j.org/1.8/org/neo4j/tooling/GlobalGraphOperations.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
//start n = node( * )
//match n-[ * ]-relatedTo_Bidirectional
//return n,relatedTo_Bidirectional

start n = node( * )
match n-[ * ]->relatedTo_Unidirectional
return n,relatedTo_Unidirectional
```

The first one will return all the relationships irrespective of direction

The second one, however, will only return the relationships which are directed to a particular node from the source node